# Material UI create link in cell

Tags: material-ui

I have a Material UI table and I have seen examples of clicking on a row and editing the entire row.  But is it possible to make a cell in a column a hyperlink?  (just the cells in one column not the the whole row)

Comment: can you please share the code you've tried?

Answer (score 4):

As discussed in the documentation for [TableCell](https://material-ui.com/api/table-cell/), you can set each cell to be a link and pass a `href` through to the link:

```
<TableCell numeric component="a" href="https://google.com">Calories</TableCell>
```

If you chose that route, you are going to have to do some styling to make sure that the linked table cells look like the other ones.

You can also wrap the content of each cell in an `<a>` tag, or set each `TableCell` to be a button and work with the `onClick` method.